# Varargs in method overloading in Java

Tags: java, overloading, variadic-functions, java-6

The following code doesn't compile.

```
package varargspkg;

public class Main {

    public static void test(int... i) {
        for (int t = 0; t < i.length; t++) {
            System.out.println(i[t]);
        }

        System.out.println("int");
    }

    public static void test(float... f) {
        for (int t = 0; t < f.length; t++) {
            System.out.println(f[t]);
        }

        System.out.println("float");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test(1, 2);  //Compilation error here quoted as follows.
    }
}
```

A compile-time error is issued.

> reference to test is ambiguous, both method test(int...) in
>   varargspkg.Main and method test(float...) in varargspkg.Main match

It seems to be obvious because the parameter values in the method call `test(1, 2);` can be promoted to `int` as well as `float`

If anyone or both of the parameters are suffixed by `F` or `f`, it compiles.

---

If we however, represent the receiving parameters in the method signature with respective wrapper types as follows

```
public static void test(Integer... i) {
    System.out.println("Integer" + Arrays.asList(i));
}

public static void test(Float... f) {
    System.out.println("Float" + Arrays.asList(f));
}
```

then the call to the method `test(1, 2);` doesn't issue any compilation error. The method to be invoked in this case is the one that accepts one `Integer` varargs parameter (the first one in the preceding snippet).

Why is in this case the error as in the first case not reported? It appears that auto-boxing and automatic type promotion are both applied here. Is auto-boxing applied first so that the error is resolved?

The Oracle docs says,

> Generally speaking, you should not overload a varargs method, or it
>   will be difficult for programmers to figure out which overloading gets
>   called.

The last sentence in this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html). It's however for the sake of better understanding varargs.

Also to add below code compiles just fine.

```
public class OverLoading {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        load(1);
    }

    public static void load(int i) {
        System.out.println("int");
    }

    public static void load(float i) {
        System.out.println("float");
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

The following is the [snap shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjmFa.png) that indicates the compilation error. I have created a new application therefore the package name is different.

[image]

I'm using JDK 6.

Comment: Your original code works fine for me. Output was
1
2
int

Comment: @techfoobar - The code in the very first snippet doesn't compile for me (with jdk 6, NetBeans 6.9.1). It produces the compilation error as specified. Does it really compile for you?

Comment: Good question. Would like to add that it gets resolved when we overwrite single paramter (int) and (float). I smell a bug here.

Comment: @techfoobar what jdk are you using?

Comment: @subirkumarsao - Working fine on JRE 7 as well as JDK 1.6.0_25

Comment: @Tiny - Compiled fine. Obviously I had to remove the package statement at the top, since i don't have that folder in my local workstation.

Comment: @techfoobar - Edited to include the image snap that demonstrates that it fails to compile in my environment.

Comment: FYI, similar Question, [Varargs Java Ambiguous Call](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31627236/642706).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either `Widen` or `Box` but you cannot do both, unless you are `boxing and widening` to `Object` (An int to Integer(Boxing) and then Integer to Object(Widening) is legal, since every class is a subclass of `Object`, so it is possible for `Integer` to be passed to `Object` parameter)

Similarly an `int` to `Number` is also legal (int -> Integer -> Number)
Since Number is the super class of `Integer` it is possible.

**Let's see this in your example:**

```
public static void test(Integer...i)

public static void test(Float...f)
```

There are some rules that are followed when selecting which overloaded method to select, when Boxing, Widening, and Var-args are combined:

2. Primitive widening uses the `smallest` method argument possible
3. Wrapper type cannot be widened to another Wrapper type
4. You can Box from int to Integer and widen to Object but no to Long
5. Widening beats Boxing, Boxing beats Var-args.
6. You can Box and then Widen   (An `int` can become `Object` via `Integer`)
7. You cannot Widen and then Box (An `int` cannot become `Long`)
8. You cannot combine var-args, with either widening or boxing

So, based on the above given rules:

**When you pass two integers to above functions,**

- according to rule 3, it will have to be first `Widened` and then
  `Boxed` to fit into a `Long`, which is illegal according to rule 5 (You cannot Widen and then Box).
- So, it is Boxed to store in `Integer` var-args.

But in first case, where you have methods with `var-args` of primitive types:

```
public static void test(int...i)
public static void test(float...f)
```

Then `test(1, 2)` can invoke both the methods (Since neither of them is more suitable for `rule 1` to apply):

- In first case it will be `var-args`
- In second case, it will be Widening and then Var-args (which is allowed)

Now, when you have methods with exactly one int and one float:

```
public static void test(int i)
public static void test(float f)
```

Then on invoking using `test(1)`, rule 1 is followed, and smallest possible widening (i.e. the `int` where no widening is needed at all) is chosen. So 1st method will be invoked.

For more information, you can refer to [`JLS - Method Invocation Conversion`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3)

Comment: @Tiny. I think you should have a look at what I have explained. I think it will be clear for you. :)

Comment: Rohit, to be precise, there's no such thing as *boxing an `int` to an instance of `Object`*. What happens, actually, when you pass an `int` to a function that takes an `Object` is that the `int` is autoboxed to an instance of `Integer`, which can be seen as an `Object` since every class inherits from Object. To verify this, `class x { boolean b(Object o) { return o.getClass() == Object.class;} void main(String... args) { System.out.println(b(1)); }}` will print false. Obviously, changing to `o.getClass() instanceof Object` will print true.

Comment: (and this is the reason why it is also legal to pass an `int` to a method that takes an instance of `Number` as a parameter -- `Integer` inherits from `Number`)

Comment: @BrunoReis Yeah I wrote that thing only in a direct way.. I should have written it clearly. :)

Answer (score 2):

In Java, `1` is how you represent an `int`. It can be either auto-boxed to an instance of `Integer` or promoted to `float`, and this explains why the compiler can't decide on the method it should call. But it will never be auto-boxed to `Long` or `Float` (or any other type).

On the other hand, if you write `1F`, it is the representation of a `float`, that can be auto-boxed to a `Float` (and, in the same spirit, will never be auto-boxed to an `Integer` or anything else).

Answer (score 2):

In Java 6, the problem lies at the time of `instantiation` of your generics before finding which method is available to call.

```
When you write 1,2 
     -> it can be be both int[] or float[] and hence the issue being complained.

When you write 1,2F 
     -> it can be be only float[] and hence the NO issue being complained.
```

Same with other two option i.e.

```
When you write 1F,2 
     -> it can be be only float[] and hence the NO issue being complained.

When you write 1F,2F 
     -> it can be be only float[] and hence the NO issue being complained.
```

On the other hand, when you use `int` or `float`, there is no variable type instantiation. When you use `1`, it tries to find method with `int` as argument first, if not, it promotes the type and identifies the method with float. If both methods available, one with the `int` will be used first.

**Ambiguity issue will not come in Java 7** as it has better handling of data type check and promotion.

Comment: With your logic it should also give an error when we overwrite single parameter int and float. But its not giving any error.  public class OverLoading {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  load(1);
 }
 
 public static void load(int i){
  System.out.println("int");
 }
 
 public static void load(float i){
  System.out.println("float");
 }
}

Comment: When you override even the single parameter e.g. `1, 2F`, being one param as strict float, the only applicable method is `test(float..)` and not `main(int..)`. That how there is no ambiguity and hence no issue.

Comment: So you say the output to example (now added to the question) will output float?

Comment: Yes . If passed 1,2F, it will output float

Comment: Surprise surprise it outputs int. Check yourself.

Comment: I think we are on different tracks. I am talking about the last piece of code in the question class OverLoading. Lets take it on chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17996/discussion-between-subirkumarsao-and-yogendra-singh)

Answer (score 2):

> Why is in this case the error as in the first case not reported? It appears that auto-boxing and automatic type promotion are both applied here. Is auto-boxing applied first the error is resolved?

Just an opinion - in case of varargs the JVM actually has to create an array of arguments. In case of Integer and Float, it's obvious what type of array it should create. So, it probably might be the reason for no ambiguity error.

But still, it's kind of confusing, why it can't create an array of Integers, when by default 1, 3 are ints.

Looks like this has been discussed here in SO in the past [**bug with varargs and overloading?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521293/bug-with-varargs-and-overloading) and is infact [**a bug**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2521374/738746), according to the discussion.