# reference to call ambiguous in java

Tags: java

```
class A {

    public void printFirst(int... va) throws IOException{
        System.out.print("A");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            new B().printFirst(2);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}


class B extends A {

    //@Override
    public void printFirst(float... va) throws IOException{
        System.out.print("B");

    }
}
```

Why, it is showing **reference to call ambiguous** ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually compiles if you remove the varargs notation. The literal `2` should be considered an `int`, not a `float`, so I would expect that the printFirst in A would be chosen by the compiler.

It looks like this has to do with how the compiler does method invocation conversions. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879910/varargs-in-method-overloading-in-java) says it's in the spec, but the part of accepted answer that relates to this question appears to be contradictory (it says you can't combine a widening conversion (int to float) with varargs, but then later it says this is okay). A similar problem was discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521293/bug-with-varargs-and-overloading) and the accepted answer concludes that this case is actually unspecified (unfortunately the link to the discussion is now broken). Making matters worse, the language guide simply suggests [avoiding this type of overloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html).

Comment: I'm not sure why you're discussing what other SO questions and answers have to say about the spec, instead of just consulting the spec directly. But oddly, it seems pretty clear from the spec that this should *not* be an error: the version with `int...` is strictly more specific than the version with `float...` (since `int <: float` and not `float <: int`), so the version with `int...` should be preferred. (See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5.) So this seems like a compiler bug.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in your compiler; I can reproduce your compile-error in one compiler (Eclipse), but not in another (`javac`), and I believe the latter is correct.

According to [§15.12.2.5 "Choosing the Most Specific Method" of *The Java Language Specification*, Java SE 7 Edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5), the compile-error that you're seeing should only happen if "no method is the most specific, because there are two or more methods that are maximally specific" (plus various other restrictions). But that's not the case here: in your case, `B.printFirst(float...)` is *not* maximally specific, because a method is *maximally specific* "if it is accessible and applicable and there is no other method that is applicable and accessible that is strictly more specific", and in your case, `A.printFirst(int...)` is strictly more specific, because `int` is a subtype of `float` and `float` is not a subtype of `int`.

By the way, your `class B` is most likely a red herring; in Eclipse, at least, you can trigger the same compile-error by simply writing:

```
class A
{
    public static void printFirst(float... va)
        { System.out.print("float..."); }
    public static void printFirst(int... va)
        { System.out.print("int..."); }
    public static void main(String args[])
       { printFirst(2); }
}
```