# Var arg methods causing error in client code

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I was trying to figure out the ins-and-outs of varargs and wrote the following code

```
public class VarArgTest {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    VarArgTest v = new VarArgTest();
    //Code 1
    System.out.println("haha");
}

public void m1(Integer a, Integer... ints) {
    System.out.println("1");
}

public void m1(Integer... ints) {
    System.out.println("2");
}
}
```

Now if I replace Code 1 by

```
v.m1(new Integer(1), new Integer(2));
```

I get the following message

```
The method m1(Integer, Integer[]) is ambiguous for the type VarArgTest
```

My question is, why throw the error at client code? Should it not be caught by compiler while defining the two m1 methods?

Comment: this could be a help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879910/varargs-in-method-overloading-in-java

Comment: @Habib Thanks for the link. But my question still stands, can the compiler not issue a warning at least?

Answer (score 4):

It's not an error in the overloads because there are still unambiguous invocations of those two methods.

```
v.m1(new Integer[] {1, 2})
```

and

```
v.m1(1, new Integer[] {2})
```

would both work just fine.  It only becomes ambiguous when the compiler has to figure out how to turn the arguments in the invocation into arrays.

Comment: Fair enough, but surely the compiler can give a warning?

Comment: Take that part up with javac.  :-)

Comment: Heh. May just need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

That means that those two methods cannot be distinguished when you would call

```
 v.m1(1,2,3,4)
```

compilator does not know which method should be used.

You need to have different parameters (method signatures) when you overload.

e.g. this would be ok for compilator :

```
   public void m1(String a, Integer... ints) {
    System.out.println("1");
   }

   public void m1(Integer... ints) {
    System.out.println("2");
   }
```

Comment: Agreed. I would not recommend my code above. The question is why Java compiler allows that without even a warning.