# Method overloading with variable argument

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I think this would be a stupid question a little bit, but I can not sure why it is.

code;

```
public class OverloadingTest {
    public static int sum(int ...a){
        int sum=0;
        for(int i : a){
            sum += i;
        }
        System.out.print("this is variant args//");
        return sum;
    }

    public static double sum(double a, double b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sum(1.5, 2.5));
        System.out.println(sum(10, 20));
        System.out.println(sum(10, 20,30));
    }
}
```

results I expected;

```
4.0
this is variant args//30
this is variant args//60
```

actual results in console:

> ```
> 4.0
> 30.0
> this is variant args//60
> ```

I can not sure why results of `sum(10, 20)` 30.0, not 30 of variable argument.

Comment: You should look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1572371/2508646)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the compiler always makes the choice to use the most specific method.

Since your second invocation has two arguments, and an `int` can be converted to a `double` without loss of precision (see [JLS, section 5.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)), the compiler elects to call your two-argument method.

An IDE will warn you here about the implicit `int` to `double` conversion.

---

edit: as @OlegEterkhin mentions in comments, see [JLS, section 15.2.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) for the process used by the compiler to select which method will be used.

And no, this won't work:

```
int x = sum(10, 20);
```

Comment: It's not really the JVM that makes the choice here - it's the compiler.

Comment: [JLS 15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) is the relevant part of the speci and it is even quite readable.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is in [JLS section 15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2). Basically, the compiler tries to find any applicable method *without* having to expand varargs, only using varargs if it has to:

> The remainder of the process is split into three phases, to ensure compatibility with versions of the Java programming language prior to Java SE 5.0. The phases are:
>
> - The first phase (§15.12.2.2) performs overload resolution without permitting boxing or unboxing conversion, or the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the second phase. [...]
> - The second phase (§15.12.2.3) performs overload resolution while allowing boxing and unboxing, but still precludes the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the third phase. [...]
> - The third phase (§15.12.2.4) allows overloading to be combined with variable arity methods, boxing, and unboxing.

In this case, the first phase *does* find a match, as `sum(double, double)` is applicable for the call `sum(10, 20)` due to the implicit conversion from `int` to `double`.

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```
System.out.println(sum(10, 20));
```

The *number* of the parameters match the signature of `sum(double a, double b)` and it's the *most* accurate method and it's the one chosen by the *compiler*.

See [15.12.2. Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon this post [Varargs in method overloading in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879910/varargs-in-method-overloading-in-java)

There are some rules that are followed when selecting which overloaded method to select, when Boxing, Widening, and Var-args are combined: -

```
Primitive widening uses the smallest method argument possible
Wrapper type cannot be widened to another Wrapper type
You can Box from int to Integer and widen to Object but no to Long
Widening beats Boxing, Boxing beats Var-args.
You can Box and then Widen (An int can become Object via Integer)
You cannot Widen and then Box (An int cannot become Long)
You cannot combine var-args, with either widening or boxing
```

Answer (score 1):

Type inference has a sort of priority over the varargs. Since you call a method with 2 arguments, it tries to find a match with 2 arguments (even with type inference) before searching for varargs methods (even with the right type).

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is defined in the [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2). "Variable arity methods, boxing, and unboxing " are handled in the third phase of method signature resolution, after first trying to match the signature without using variable arity methods.