# Primitive vararg parameters in method overloading

Tags: java, arrays, overloading, variadic-functions, primitive

Primitives are at it again, breaking rules, I learned before. Well not technically primitive but composed of them.

I learned that whenever there's no method more specific than rest, compile time error occurs as it happens here.

```
public static void caller(){
    z5();  // Error. Neither Integer, nor String is more specific
    z5(null);  // Error for the same reason
}
public static void z5(Integer...integers){
    System.out.println("Integer z5 called");
}
public static void z5(String...strings){
    System.out.println("String z5 called");
}
```

Now comes primitives into the picture.

```
public static void caller(){
    z1(null);  // Error cuz [I, [J, [F all are subclass of Object.
    z1();  // SURPRISINGLY works and calls the int one. WHY?
}
public static void z1(int...integers){
    System.out.println("int z1 called");
}
public static void z1(long...longs){
    System.out.println("long z1 called");
}
public static void z1(float...floats){
    System.out.println("float z1 called");
}
```

Expected compile time errors occurs here.

```
public static void caller(){
    z1(null);  // Error
    z1();  // Error
}
public static void z1(int...integers){
    System.out.println("int z1 called");
}
public static void z1(boolean...bools){
    System.out.println("bool z1 called");
}
```

Now my question is, int[], float[], or any array of primitives are not primitive types then Why are they treated differently than other reference types?

--UPDATE--

[@john16384](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1262865/john16384) You don't think I read your "Possible duplicate" [Varargs in method overloading in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879910/varargs-in-method-overloading-in-java)

Top answer there says **You cannot combine var-args, with either widening or boxing**. Besides I forgot to mention, OP's code posted there, works fine on my jdk 7.

What exactly is going on which works for **(int...is) & (float...fs)** but not for **(Integer...is) & (Float...fs)** and not for **(int...is)** & **(boolean...bool)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from the JLS about varargs invocations when multiple methods are applicable:

> 15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method
>
> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a
>   method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the
>   descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming
>   language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.
>
> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than
>   another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed
>   on to the other one without a compile-time error. In cases such as an
>   explicitly typed lambda expression argument (§15.27.1) or a variable
>   arity invocation (§15.12.2.4), some flexibility is allowed to adapt
>   one signature to the other.

The important part here is how methods are defined to be more specific.  It basically says that `int...` is more specific than `long...` because any values you could pass to the first method could also be passed to the second method.

This will also apply to the case where you pass no arguments.  `int...` will be the most specific (it will even see `byte...` as more specific!).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    bla();
}

private static void bla(long... x) {}
private static void bla(int... x) {}
private static void bla(short... x) {}
private static void bla(byte... x) {}   // <-- calls this one
```

The reason you get an error when also creating an overload `boolean...` is that it now is ambigious which one to call, and the compiler stops before getting to the point where it has to pick the most specific method.

Comment: I didn't see this well described in the duplicate I linked, so I removed that comment.

Comment: However if I replace the primitives with their respective Wrapper classes, it gives me an error. Why doesn't the method with `Short` get called ? Isn't it more specific, as you just described ? @john16384

Comment: @Shashwat That's because those are objects and they follow the subtyping rules for objects.  `Short` is not a subclass of `Integer`.

Comment: @Anurag Awashti In JLS 4.10 it explains sub typing.  For primitives there are rules defined in JLS 4.10.1

Comment: Sorry but why does it not work for null? Is null parameter a special case? Or is  it a different question altogether?

Comment: @Anurag Awashti I didn't check this extensively, but primitives cannot be null, so it would have to box the null to one of the wrapper types, and since there are multiple options it would be ambigious.  If you then tried casting it, it will fail again because `null` cannot be unboxed to a primitive again.