# Behavior of method overloading with varargs

Tags: java, overloading, variadic-functions

I have two overloaded methods with varargs int and long. When I run a test passing integer it seems to prefer the varargs long method. Whereas, if I make the methods static and run with an integer it seems to prefer the varargs int method. What's going on here?

```
void varargs(int... i){

    System.out.println("Inside int varargs");
    for(int x : i)
        System.out.println(x);
}

void varagrs(long... l){

    System.out.println("Inside long varargs");
    for(long x : l)
        System.out.println(x);
}

static void staticvarargs(int...i)
{
    System.out.println("Inside static int varargs");
    for(int x : i)
        System.out.println(x);
}

static void staticvarargs(long...l)
{
    System.out.println("Inside static long varargs");
    for(long x : l)
        System.out.println(x);
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    VarArgs va = new VarArgs();
    va.varagrs(1);
    staticvarargs(1);
}
```

Output:

Inside long varargs
1

Inside static int varargs
1

EDIT: I should've chosen better method names. There was a typo varargs, varagrs. Thanks zhong.j.yu for pointing that out.

**Corrected code and expected behavior:**

```
void varargs(int... i){

    System.out.println("Inside int varargs");
    for(int x : i)
        System.out.println(x);
}

void varargs(long... l){

    System.out.println("Inside long varargs");
    for(long x : l)
        System.out.println(x);
}

static void staticvarargs(int...i)
{
    System.out.println("Inside static int varargs");
    for(int x : i)
        System.out.println(x);
}

static void staticvarargs(long...l)
{
    System.out.println("Inside static long varargs");
    for(long x : l)
        System.out.println(x);
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    VarArgs va = new VarArgs();
    va.varargs(1);
    staticvarargs(1);
}
```

Output:

Inside int varargs
1

Inside static int varargs
1

Comment: While I can't explain the behaviour, this is probably the sought of confusion that prompted Oracle to explicitly suggest vararg methods are not overloaded [in the Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521293/bug-with-varargs-and-overloading

Comment: @Evgeny That's a different issue, isn't it?

Comment: Yes added it for completeness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a typo

```
void varagrs(long... l){
         ^^
```

That's why it's nice to have an IDE with spell checking (e.g. IntelliJ)

After fixing the typo, the compiler chooses `(int...)` over `(long...)` because `int` is a subtype of `long` [(4.10.1)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.1), so the 1st method is more specific [(15.12.2.5)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5-300). Note though `int[]` is not a subtype of `long[]` [(4.10.3)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.3).