# Var-args overloading

Tags: java, overloading, variadic-functions

Could anyone please explain why this code throws an ambiguous overload error, surely the Integer method is more specific and applicable?

Thanks,

Ned

```
package object_orientation;
public class Ambiguous {
    //ambiguous error compiler unsure whether boxing is needed or not
    static void overload(Integer... d){
        System.out.println("Integer");
    }

    static void overload(long... d){
        System.out.println("Long");
    }

    public static void main(String a[]){
        int i = 1;
        overload(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: see that `Integer` is different from `int`. `Integer` is a wrapper.

Comment: good post on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521293/bug-with-varargs-and-overloading

Comment: if you change `long...` to `long` in your overload method, it will compile.  I believe varargs translate to being an array at compile time so I think that's where the ambiguity is happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These concepts in Java should help,
`Boxing + Widening is allowed`, but `not Widening + Boxing`.

These rules of Widening, Boxing and Vararg should help:

> 1. Primitive Widening > Boxing > Varargs.
> 2. Widening and Boxing (WB) not allowed.
> 3. Boxing and Widening (BW) allowed.
> 4. While overloading, Widening + vararg and Boxing + vararg can only be
>      used in a mutually exclusive manner
> 5. Widening between wrapper classes not allowed.
> 6. Widening+varArgs & Boxing+varargs are individually allowed (but not allowed in overloaded version of method).
> 7. Boxing+Widening is preferred over Boxing+Varargs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I thought the int would simply be boxed and applied to the Integer var-args and the long var-args ignored, because you can't widen and box at the same time. The compiler tells me I have an Ambiguous error of type Ambiguous