# Overloading function using varargs

Tags: java, overloading, variadic-functions

This will not compile:

```
public class Methods
{

    public static void method(Integer... i)
    {
        System.out.print("A");
    }

    public static void method(int... i)
    {
        System.out.print("B");
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        method(7);
    }
}
```

This will compile and work:

```
public class Methods
{

    public static void method(Integer i)
    {
        System.out.print("A");
    }

    public static void method(int i)
    {
        System.out.print("B");
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        method(7);
    }
}
```

First and second example are very similar. First uses varargs, second not. Why one works, second not. 7 is primitive, so second method should be called in both cases. Is it normal behaviour?

I found it:
[Bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6199075)
[Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521293/bug-with-varargs-and-overloading)

Comment: which one is being called? i guess B

Comment: probably worth removing the question since it already has an SO entry as well as a real bug report.

Comment: Yes, 7 is primitive, so B in output in second case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [bug with varargs and overloading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521293/bug-with-varargs-and-overloading)

Comment: @Steve P. In version 7, the problem should be solved, there are 2 primitives. Here I have object and primitive.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for link to bug report too. I would disagree that the the examples are very similar though - the first one has two methods each of which has an Array as an argument.  The two methods in the second have unique signatures, 1 with a Class, 1 with a primitive.

Comment: still a problem in java 7 by the way

Comment: I wonder, whether this is a bug, or normal. Should be "B" in both cases?

Comment: I think it is not a bug of Java. When compiler compile the line 'method(7);' the compiler get ambiguous and can't determine which 'method' will be called because Boxing & Unboxing feature.

Comment: passing array as paramater works

Comment: Passing array works because compiler won't get ambiguous in this case. BTW. You should not design overload like this.

Comment: It is question similar to exemplary questions in OCPJP exam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a high-level informal summary of what is going on.

Firstly varargs syntax is really just syntactic sugaring for passing an array.  So `method(7)` is actually going to pass an array of ... something.

But an array of what?  There are two options here corresponding to the two overloads of the method; i.e an `int[]` or a `Integer[]`.

If there are two or more overloads that could work (i.e. right method names, right numbers of arguments, convertible values) then the resolution process will chose the overload that is an exact match over a match that requires conversions, and complain if the only candidates require conversions.  (This is a drastic simplification of the rules ... see the JLS [section 15.12](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) for the complete story ... and be prepared for a long / difficult read!)

So what is happening in your first example is that it is trying to decide between two methods that both require conversions; i.e. `int` to `int[]` versus `int` to `Integer[]`.  Basically it cannot decide which alternative to use.  Hence a compilation error that says that the *call* is ambiguous.

If you change the varargs call to a call passing an explicit `Integer[]` or `int[]`, you now get an exact match to one of the two overloads ... and the rules above say that this is not ambiguous.

---

> I understand it as: 7 is primitive so it should be converted to array - `int[]`.

The problem is that `7` can *also* be converted to an `Integer[]` ... by auto-boxing the `int` first.

Comment: I understand it as: 7 is primitive so it should be converted to array - int[].

Comment: We can distinguish both. It should be: 7 - converted to int[], Integer(7) - converted to Integer[]. Second example works and it is able to distinguish.

Comment: @Pawel - That's not the way the language is specified.  The JLS says that `int` can be converted to `Integer[]` in the context of a varargs call.  The fact that you (the programmer) can distinguish the cases and (intuitively) say which conversion is "right" does not help the compiler.  The compiler is bound by the rules, and the rules say this is ambiguous.

Comment: I know, but the rule is a bit strange, isnt't it? But I understand the rule and what's is going on. It works for array, it doesn't work for one argument.

Comment: Now you are getting into a subjective topic ... whether the rule is "strange" or not.  Bear in mind that both auto-boxing and varags were retro-fitted into an earlier design for Java.  The rules for method overload resolution in Java 5 and later *had to be* consistent with what Java 4 and earlier did ... when those constructs weren't part of the language.

Comment: As a side-note, many languages avoid this problem entirely by not supporting method/constructor overloading.  For example, Python and Ceylon.  In the case of Ceylon, this decision is clearly a reaction to the linguistic and usability problems that overloading can cause in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple arguments must be passed in an array, but the `varargs` hides the process. In the above `varargs` method, parameter acts as an `int` array with a reference name.
So if you change it to:

```
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int[] s = {7};
        method(s);
    }
```

first class will compile and work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is rather difficult. But it is described in the [JLS §15.12. Method Invocation Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12). In these specifications, "*variable arity*" methods are methods with variable number of arguments, so varargs.

**[§15.12.2.4.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.4) Phase 3: Identify Applicable Variable Arity Methods**

> The method m is an applicable variable-arity method if and only if all
>   of the following conditions hold:
>
> - For 1 ≤ i < n, the type of e<sub>i</sub>, A<sub>i</sub>, can be converted by method
>     invocation conversion to S<sub>i</sub>.
> - If k ≥ n, then for n ≤ i ≤ k, the type of e<sub>i</sub>, A<sub>i</sub>, can be converted by
>     method invocation conversion to the component type of S<sub>n</sub>.
> - If k != n, or if k = n and An cannot be converted by method invocation
>     conversion to S<sub>n</sub>[], then the type which is the erasure (§4.6) of S<sub>n</sub> is
>     accessible at the point of invocation.
> - If m is a generic method as described above, then U<sub>l</sub> `<:`
>     B<sub>l</sub>[R<sub>1</sub>=U<sub>1</sub>...,R<sub>p</sub>=U<sub>p</sub>] (1 ≤ l ≤ p).
>
> If no applicable variable arity method is found, a compile-time error
>   occurs.
>
> Otherwise, **the most specific method ([§15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)) is chosen among the
>   applicable variable-arity methods.**

So, we should look further to [§15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5).

**[§15.12.2.5.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) Choosing the Most Specific Method**

> One variable arity member method named `m` is more specific than another
>   variable arity member method of the same name if either:
>
> 1. One member method has n parameters and the other has k parameters,
>      where n ≥ k, and:
>
>    - The types of the parameters of the first member method are T<sub>1</sub>, ...,
>        T<sub>n-1</sub>, T<sub>n</sub>[].
>    - The types of the parameters of the other method are U<sub>1</sub>, ..., U<sub>k-1</sub>,
>        Uk[].
>    - If the second method is generic then let R<sub>1</sub> ... R<sub>p</sub> (p ≥ 1) be its type
>        parameters, let B<sub>l</sub> be the declared bound of R<sub>l</sub> (1 ≤ l ≤ p), let A<sub>1</sub> ...
>        A<sub>p</sub> be the type arguments inferred (§15.12.2.7) for this invocation
>        under the initial constraints T<sub>i</sub> << U<sub>i</sub> (1 ≤ i ≤ k-1) and T<sub>i</sub> << U<sub>k</sub> (k ≤
>        i ≤ n), and let S<sub>i</sub> = U<sub>i</sub>[R<sub>1</sub>=A<sub>1</sub>,...,R<sub>p</sub>=A<sub>p</sub>] (1 ≤ i ≤ k).
>    - Otherwise, let S<sub>i</sub> = U<sub>i</sub> (1 ≤ i ≤ k).
>    - For all j from 1 to k-1, T<sub>j</sub> `<:` S<sub>j</sub>, and,
>    - For all j from k to n, T<sub>j</sub> `<:` S<sub>k</sub>, and,
>    - If the second method is a generic method as described above, then
>        A<sub>l</sub> `<:` B<sub>l</sub>[R<sub>1</sub>=A<sub>1</sub>,...,R<sub>p</sub>=A<sub>p</sub>] (1 ≤ l ≤ p).

(`T <: S` means *T is a subtype of S*)

Your methods do not match these conditions, so there is no "*Most Specific*" method. So, it says a little bit further:

> It is possible that no method is the most specific, because there are
>   two or more methods that are maximally specific. In this case:
>
> - If all the maximally specific methods have override-equivalent
>     (§8.4.2) signatures, then:
>
>   - If exactly one of the maximally specific methods is not declared
>       abstract, it is the most specific method.
>   - Otherwise, if all the maximally specific methods are declared
>       abstract, and the signatures of all of the maximally specific methods
>       have the same erasure (§4.6), then the most specific method is chosen
>       arbitrarily among the subset of the maximally specific methods that
>       have the most specific return type.
>
>     However, the most specific method is considered to throw a checked
>       exception if and only if that exception or its erasure is declared in
>       the throws clauses of each of the maximally specific methods.
> - **Otherwise, we say that the method invocation is ambiguous, and a
>     compile-time error occurs.**

So, the conclusion: your methods are ambiguous following the JLS.