# Why are foo(double d, Object...) and foo(Object...) ambiguous in Java, but not foo(Double d, Object...) and foo(Object...)?

Tags: java, overload-resolution

**Note**: this question has been marked as a duplicate of [Ambiguous varargs methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874380/ambiguous-varargs-methods) but it is not a duplicate. That question deals with confusion between `Integer`/`int` (here, it would be `Double`/`double`). But my question deals with ambiguity between `double`/lack of `double`, and puzzles about the *lack* of ambiguity when using `Double` instead.

Why does Java disambiguate based on `Double` but not `double` in the cases below?

```
public class Ambiguity {

    void foo(double d, Object... o) {}

    void foo(Object... o) {}

    void bar() {
        foo(1.0d, "Hi"); // complains about ambiguity
    }

    void foo2(Double d, Object... o) {}

    void foo2(Object... o) {}

    void bar2() {
        foo2(1.0d, "Hi"); // fine
    }
}
```

Comment: I can,t find the answer of this question in the associated thread...

Comment: After reafing all the answers, without any further research nor tests the only clue I could think of is that since Double is subtype of Object the second example compiles....

Comment: Beacause Double is an Object, whereas double is not.

Comment: But that makes it sound like the version with Double would be the ambiguous one... but the opposite happens.

Comment: The answer you are looking for is indeed already been given to the question this is supposedly the duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27880923